# What is the best version of Magento?

Tags: magento2, php, module, magento-1

I will kindly appreciate if you let me know what is the difference between magento versions 1.9.2.4 and the latest one I think is 2.0.10?
I am not a developer I just build a Magento website and my VPS service advised me to download the latest Magento version .. but I just find out that it was built on 1.9.2.4 
Alos if you smart guys know some links where I can get the basic of Magento (like how to upload products)

Answer (score 2):

If you are building a new website i would recommend magento 2 as it more powerful , fast and advance (with few more bugs) than magento 1

More detail comparison you can find in below links

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/moving-from-magento-1-to-magento-2/

https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/magento-1-vs-magento-2/